# Динамический контент - возможно?

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование

Можно ли как то с помощью PHP с Javascript , показывать совершенно разный контент (html-кусок) на разных разрешениях.

Есть сложный участок на сайте , который не получится сверстать адаптивно для моб и десктопа. Можно ли этот участок сделать просто разным для каждого разрешения ?

- Допустим показывать другое содержимое , если окно браузера меньше 992px

Желательно , что-бы он менялся не только по загрузке сайта , но даже если окно увеличивать и уменьшать.

Comment: Да, возможно (можно повесить обработчик на изменение размеров окна), но я бы не рекомендовал (догружать или откуда вы будете брать контент). Вместо, можно показывать/скрывать что-то дополнительно. Менять отступы, или допустим показывать первую часть + страничность.

Comment: @nick_n_a А немного подробнее ? и почему не рекомендовали бы ? Содержание секции - текст и картинки , будут одинаковыми , но будет совершенно другая структура html. Не хочется делать поддомен для моб , но хочется максимально адаптивности. А в некоторых участках сделать красиво и понятно это не возможно.

Comment: @Vipz первая причина почему вешать событие на смену размера окна плохо - это производительность. Сайт будет ощутимо подтормаживать на при данном действии, что вызовет нехороший отклик. Я согласен с 1ым коментом - легче через mediaquery css вешать на определенный контент стили display:none , а другие блоки показывать. Минус данного подхода - страница будет тяжелой т.к. грузится сразу 2 варианта у всех.

Comment: @Vipz и много таких блоков на сайте? Если уж не координально всю разметку нужно менять — то вообще `display: none | block;` + `media query` должны помочь решить вашу проблему. Просто при одном разрешение — отображаете блок с другой разметкой, а предыдущий скрываете. А за подмену на сервере под разное разрешение — можно и бан поймать от ПС...

Comment: @AlexanderBragin за подмену такого характера (одного и того же контента , просто с разной структурой) явно ничего не будет. Я же не бананы на страпоны буду менять. А вот display:none поисковики явно не любят.

Только у 1-ой секции нужно поменять структуру.
Страница весит 900 кб , загружается DOM за 240 ms , остальное за 400 ms и того за 600+ms.

Сильно обработчик нагрузит ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без проблем:

1) Посетитель заходит на сайт JS ловит его разрешение и отправляет на сервер по AJAX

2) PHP отвечает формируя нужный DIV (блок) для этого учатска

3) JS вставляет блок в нужное место

4) На событие изменения окна вешается такой же AJAX и всё повторяется

P.S. Сколько у вас таких блоков? Не больше десятка наверное? Я бы сделал что бы PHP сразу сгенерировал все и отдал их на фронтенд, а там JS уже будет их сам менять в зависимости от разрешения и не придётся бомбить сервер запросами.